# Compiling sass via sass-maven-plugin and susy

Tags: maven, sass, compass-sass, susy-compass

I've been trying for a while now to get the sass-maven-plugin to use susy while compiling sass code via compass, without success.
The latest try involves the following code, and the assumption that susy's .scss files are really all that is needed:

pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jasig.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>sass-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <useCompass>true</useCompass>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>update-stylesheets</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

And in my project root folder I have the following in my config.rb:

```
http_path = "src/main/webapp"
css_dir = "src/main/webapp/skin/stylesheets"
sass_dir = "src/main/webapp/skin/sass"
images_dir = "src/main/webapp/skin/images"
```

Which points to all the right folders and these are found correctly.
So far so good.

In my sass folder I then have a .scss file which contains: `@import: "susy"` and in this folder I have put the `_susy.scss` file which contains:

```
@import "susy/support";
@import "susy/units";
@import "susy/settings";
...
```

Running `compass install compass` in the root folder works when I have compass but not susy installed in my ruby-setup, which means that it is working fine, right?

The problem is that when running `mvn clean install -e` in the project root I get the following error message:

```
[ERROR] Compilation of template C:/Users/.../skin/sass/XXX.scss failed: different
prefix: "" and "C:/Users/.../trunk/target/[warname]/skin/sass"
```

Am I even in the right ballpark or am I completely off track?

Comment: try to set `relative_assets = true`, see also: https://github.com/Compass/compass/issues/1170